# Shortcode output always appearing at top of page content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem about shortcode.

How can change shortcode location ?

[image: How can change shortcode location]

Comment: Question not clear

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the return just return it!

[resolved] Plugin called via shortcode appears at the wrong place on post

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-called-via-shortcode-appears-at-the-wrong-place-on-post?replies=5